# Blockchain API to determine transaction confirmations

Tags: json, bitcoin

I am trying to identify whether a transaction in the bitcoin blockchain has been confirmed or not. I have accessed a JSON representation of the transaction from blockchain.info using this url: https://blockchain.info/tx/62f9419e56ac1b628840aaf52307867f9856d7a52b3c1d945a9938a3021cbf2c?show_adv=false&format=json

I can not find anything in the response that indicates how many confirmations it has...

```
{"block_height":221580,"time":1361068368,"inputs":[{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"1NaPjDPGcfaVCBd3cTmy4zEPjRbDwzkW49","tx_index":53213157,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000,"addr":"1FDBdn8cseukiteu1myGQCfgYnncdMNpFk","tx_index":53252395,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"13QRi4W5bq3FWrNGrWGcF1dH4mSWD6Huun","tx_index":52575903,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"1MhEJx1BodWATGxoZ7az3GnmUQwx2adCG2","tx_index":53376409,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":90000000,"addr":"1FosGa87ZSjoagVu1j8djiJKzUeLkhhp6P","tx_index":53308634,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":200000,"addr":"1DZzEunCP1SxBsz2aZah2q9WAFuYSsDrq9","tx_index":53272656,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":98500000,"addr":"19q8NEgZKQcQMMx5z16JETbe1bx6StNZfj","tx_index":53506579,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"15LXjh36usUspAYsGnhURVEnPn86W7SPSu","tx_index":53532799,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":119000000,"addr":"1PNbeqfPgMjjL6sLdXqkNZyCSkGFHop3bz","tx_index":53492488,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":150000000,"addr":"153hqmnNqUM8RGWdLE12tj74aAyS9U2pe7","tx_index":53283295,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"149BGgDjaMyYfYnrja4asYtuUnpsBjobnH","tx_index":53440208,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":167,"value":35000,"addr":"1F3eAsYGC45s2Q8XiE7ywGXMr8QLB8FTCD","tx_index":53578752,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":862,"value":5000,"addr":"1CD4Dcy3yUiBejmQX1hKfJi1y5ysAX9RwZ","tx_index":53578752,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":60000000,"addr":"1Q7hDXko9U8MxoAZGmYk2se6tf8WFSQbUK","tx_index":53305081,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":98000000,"addr":"1RuMjWETvUPAUqfJKhZ4GBo5tKuszbDTA","tx_index":53521527,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"17rBkeKtc7APY5PQjbicBbucfaUA1PZSpm","tx_index":53511134,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":169216027,"addr":"1EBz5v7dJfBPJzSwivVQcY19eT5hUBxa8w","tx_index":53194652,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":80000000,"addr":"1KLn85reRxN1JZL1S3gD2Kp2x8LZ14rz6S","tx_index":53194567,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"1EppQ2h8Ddvp1vsoSb2DLJqJAws2DrYnv9","tx_index":53190665,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":174,"value":2,"addr":"1CDDR1vZtZPWc48v4brHmka3tDpXbuT9wd","tx_index":53620404,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":100000000,"addr":"12zQxFPPh5rsUyakdZZyADj2N5bFRFZRcd","tx_index":53540021,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":801624197,"addr":"1JEjtpHB7aZJm3QSRp76qQqchFfs4TjDeE","tx_index":53526428,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":100000000,"addr":"1K1Sn9V775d7i94voiYLLUSaFNUQ9BVj9Q","tx_index":53430153,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1156,"value":1,"addr":"1CxXkpmJ9Nr4S9b3rKeKU5WWLXGp5nv553","tx_index":53619724,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":99950000,"addr":"1Hp5GdoX4oXmjUD6ZRKvXNJQCZp2sk712c","tx_index":53229930,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":98000000,"addr":"12aqif4GXBd17N6EFj4onrHLd8febY4n6j","tx_index":53160076,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":357452267,"addr":"146eveRJD2YnxvNBw4hHtZn8xR3LHHVxtH","tx_index":53651895,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":60000000,"addr":"1FZximueHPa9sqTZSg2Q4LAsg91dZaJK5D","tx_index":53640062,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":100000000,"addr":"12VL7U1BLf8kLrkN3sca9w5dGVhVAy1kvD","tx_index":53578503,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":67315003,"addr":"1BbYNxYAGJJJz6wP4pK5eHmwcieRSiPDZm","tx_index":53437082,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":100000000,"addr":"1DoTTLAs5VUm2QHBXeL34h2kSfYnqSpsCj","tx_index":53116751,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":195951000,"addr":"1Epje2MuDrckP4zVJmRXyEu5jWby2MvgHy","tx_index":53599874,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":25,"value":1,"addr":"1CdACYi1JQDGekGPPc8bd3vq5d5v6s2KKY","tx_index":53620401,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":105,"value":2,"addr":"15dsKW8yotixATZdDomBkRJh7YvzJJ4z7X","tx_index":53620401,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":90000000,"addr":"17ra7TQoPSmrxvLXGhupexd3Dk9fnZLM8Q","tx_index":53675760,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"1Fm2j4k7XK8veWdeJaxDuZdujdQQh3mj9j","tx_index":53696368,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":39,"value":1500,"addr":"1PB3DrsvvTMkxv7AoV5FdMAVbrnv1R9AvF","tx_index":53366964,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":70000000,"addr":"1HDxhL7H8thYC9RaLwACRoeTP6cjTERzkq","tx_index":53197639,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":60000000,"addr":"1Mzt5Y815fnf3rbCigx411bmUGqTiAMMMf","tx_index":53534495,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":3000000,"addr":"191cP1rSfJX9kATiujqbavKPHta8ryPbUk","tx_index":53397518,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":80000000,"addr":"1E7zhSRBexQYN98PxKZrnocZzb7yuCoobF","tx_index":53616202,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":60000000,"addr":"1DNGJSkn2jaBtzHpeu2EV8Za7GzLkYRKrk","tx_index":53211317,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"1FPHkZfftpfBVYg46sBAZmU7k4R6nMWjgm","tx_index":53714935,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":80000000,"addr":"1NJmpCAfoeZa8M8RoWCT1PAs85k4URKwuL","tx_index":53437066,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":320000000,"addr":"17MCmBPgv2SEKsmGf1o7X6qbK59C1Pnwr3","tx_index":53584050,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":100000000,"addr":"1KrtH7ceJthEfBFd8t9G4Vohj2myGB1eDj","tx_index":53212472,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":103000000,"addr":"13zZzqKR3XYPUKpLWvGkimSJbDMaJim9Ru","tx_index":53218032,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":1,"value":92500000,"addr":"1G5EdCerj7Yryoc4tpmCrFe7rvkbLcjHtz","tx_index":53633538,"type":0}},{"prev_out":{"n":0,"value":97800000,"addr":"1K59Q1UJSULsHhs4Rv8PiakEhDK689jQSj","tx_index":53232395,"type":0}}],"vout_sz":2,"relayed_by":"184.71.200.221","hash":"62f9419e56ac1b628840aaf52307867f9856d7a52b3c1d945a9938a3021cbf2c","vin_sz":52,"tx_index":53744354,"ver":1,"out":[{"n":0,"value":1000000,"addr":"1cm8zPZqjfWs5MBg8yKxJwWvDAkqF4CVu","tx_index":53744354,"type":0},{"n":1,"value":5000000000,"addr":"1EGP5pSnttKRdAcPxdiTviSrjsyHEAnXhy","tx_index":53744354,"type":0}],"size":9439}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The concept of "confirmation" on Bitcoin essentially translates to how many blocks have been generated since the block containing transaction. In other words, you'll have to issue another request to get the current network block count (http://blockchain.info/q/getblockcount), and the confirmation count then becomes `current_block_count - transaction_block_height + 1`. Note that `block_height` is only present in the response if at least one block was generated since (i.e. new transactions may not even include the element).

Comment: and how do i then find out if this TX wasn't a double spent?

basically, i have the TX and the block. but if i then, 2 hours later, just calculate the current block, that doesnt mean that there was any scam and that this transaction is indeed confirmed

Comment: As I understand it, this is a probabilistic approach (enough blocks => practically zero probably of counterfeit), but I'm far from being an expert on the subject so I'll point you towards Google :-)  That being said, I don't think your comment has to do with the "how do I..." as much as with "how does it work?"

Comment: @TomerGabel No, Tim explained to you exactly how to get the number of confirmations.

Comment: @FedericoSchiocchet I don't see the explanation you're referring to. Also note the dates -- the comment is five years old and the answer is nine (!) years old :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample nodejs code to determine block count of the transaction.

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getConfirmations(transactionId) {
  try {
    const response = await 

    axios.get(`https://blockchain.info/rawtx/${transactionId}`);
    const blockHeight = response.data.block_height;
    const currentBlockHeight = await axios.get(`https://blockchain.info/latestblock`)
      .then(res => res.data.height);

    const confirmations = currentBlockHeight - blockHeight + 1;
    return confirmations;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```